# How to insert the current system timestamp into db2 database base column when .csv file is loaded

Tags: java, database, jdbc, db2

The below class will import the .csv into database table.it is working  fine and Now i need to update another column in same table where current system timestamp needs to get 
get updated when this program is executed in the respective column of the database table.

Example: In Db2 table Subjects columns are:
                   Eng     Social      Maths   TimeStamp

In .CSV file has only 3 columns Eng     Social      Maths .

When .csv file is imported (using above program) to db2 all the columns are updated except TimeStamp. 
Timestamp is inculded to tack the when .csv file is uploaded to table.
So, how to Update the TimeStamp column with Current System timestamp simultaneously .? Please help

public class CSVLoader {

```
private static final 
    String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO OPPTYMGMT.${table}
         (${keys})      VALUES(${values})";

private static final String TABLE_REGEX = "\\$\\{table\\}";

private static final String KEYS_REGEX = "\\$\\{keys\\}";

private static final String VALUES_REGEX = "\\$\\{values\\}";

private Connection connection;

private char seprator;

public CSVLoader(Connection connection) {

    this.connection = connection;

    //Set default separator

    this.seprator = ',';
}

      public void loadCSV(String csvFile, String tableName) throws Exception {

    CSVReader csvReader = null;

    if(null == this.connection) {

        throw new Exception("Not a valid connection.");
    }

    try {

        csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), this.seprator);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        throw new Exception("Error occured while executing file. "

                   + e.getMessage());

              }

        String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();

    if (null == headerRow) {

        throw new FileNotFoundException(


                        "No columns defined in given CSV file." +

                         "Please check the CSV file format.");
    }

    String questionmarks = StringUtils.repeat("?,", headerRow.length);

    questionmarks = (String) questionmarks.subSequence(0, questionmarks

            .length() - 1);


    String query = SQL_INSERT.replaceFirst(TABLE_REGEX, tableName);

    query = query
            .replaceFirst(KEYS_REGEX, StringUtils.join

             (headerRow,   ","));

    query = query.replaceFirst(VALUES_REGEX, questionmarks);

            System.out.println("Query: " + query);

    String[] nextLine;

    Connection con = null;

    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {
        con = this.connection;

        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

                       final int batchSize = 1000;

                     int count = 0;

        Date date = null;

        while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {

            System.out.println( "inside while" );

            if (null != nextLine) {

                int index = 1;

                for (String string : nextLine) {

                    date = DateUtil.convertToDate(string);

        if (null != date) {

                    ps.setDate(index++, new java.sql.Date(date

                    .getTime()));

                     } else {

                  ps.setString(index++, string);

    System.out.println( "string" +string);

                    }

                }

                ps.addBatch();

            }

            if (++count % batchSize == 0) {

                ps.executeBatch();

            }

                     }


        ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records

        con.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        con.rollback();

        e.printStackTrace();

        throw new Exception(

        "Error occured while loading data 

                from file                to                      database."

               + e.getMessage());

    } finally {

             if (null != ps)


            ps.close();

        if (null != con)

            con.close();

            System.out.println("csvReader will be closed");

        csvReader.close();

    }

}

public char getSeprator() {

    return seprator;

}

public void setSeprator(char seprator) {

    this.seprator = seprator;

}


         }
```

Comment: usually you have a trigger on the database table itself, that updates the timestamp. this ensures, that no matter which software (or even the an admin via sql) changes the table, the timestamp is allways correct. I would not implement it any other way ever...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static final 
 String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO OPPTYMGMT.${table}
     (${keys}, my_timestamp_column)      VALUES(${values}, current_timestamp)";
```

Comment: Hi mustaccio, Thank U VERY MUCH :-). The Above solution Worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat cDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
Date now = new Date();
String ccDate = cDate.format(now);
```

Will get the current time and insert the string ccDate into the DB.
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077520/how-to-load-the-values-of-csv-file-into-a-sql-database/18078137#18078137)

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Thanks for the quick reply. I am confused Where, I need to palce the above code which u mention in my code?

Comment: Please check the above mentioned example

Answer (score 0):

When using the expression current system, it could mean the system where Java is executed OR the system where DB2 is executed.

You can get the Java date with the previous answer.

For the DB2 date you should provide this in the insert statement

```
current date
```

For example, for a table

```
create table t1 (date date)

insert into t1 values (current date)
```

- Current date special register http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005870.html

Finally, if you really want to import data into DB2, it is better to use the IMPORT or LOAD commands, instead of recreate your own tool.

- LOAD http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html
- IMPORT http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html

Comment: You could have corrected my answer instead of create a new one :p