# DB2 CURRENT TIMESTAMP - ERROR [22003] [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0111E Numeric value out of range. SQLSTATE=22003

Tags: c#, sql, timestamp, db2, odbc

I am trying to do an insert into our DB2 table.

```
OdbcConnection db2Connection = new OdbcConnection();
db2Connection.ConnectionString = "Dsn=DB2T;Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};uid=xxxxxxx;pwd=xxxxx;Regional=No";

OdbcDataAdapter daDB2 = new OdbcDataAdapter();
OdbcCommand insertDB2HourlyCommand = db2Connection.CreateCommand();

string sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO " + tableName +
                               + @" VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                                            ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                                            ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

One of these parameters is a TIMESTAMP field, which I have tried various methods to insert CURRENT TIMESTAMP...

insertDB2HourlyCommand
    .Parameters
    .Add("@ROW_TS", OdbcType.VarChar)
    .Value = "CURRENT TIMESTAMP";

insertDB2HourlyCommand
    .Parameters
    .Add("@ROW_TS", OdbcType.Timestamp)
    .Value = ("TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-09 13:43:00.578073'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FFFFFF')");
```

The error message I keep getting is

> ERROR [22003] [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0111E  Numeric value out of range. SQLSTATE=22003.

I've tried playing with the OdbcType and the parameter value to no avail. I am running out of ideas.

Comment: replace `?` with `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` in actual query string instead of binding parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert the current system timestamp into db2 database base column when .csv file is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225333/how-to-insert-the-current-system-timestamp-into-db2-database-base-column-when-c)

Comment: Or supply it with a "right this instant" date/time value from the host application language (slightly dangerous if they've messed with the clock, though, depending on where this runs from).